# TCP server not shutting down the pc

Tags: java, tcp

I wrote a  Java `TCP` server program to shutdown my PC from a client.It is successfully receiving message from the client but it is not shutting down the PC 
Someone please help me to fix this

here is my **code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerSideSocket {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4020);  //Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4020");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4020");

        while (true) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
 if(message=="shutdown"){

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t ");
System.exit(0);

 }
 else if(message=="restart"){
Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc2 = runtime1.exec("shutdown -r -t ");
System.exit(0);


 }

                System.out.println(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because `shutdown` is privileged. Have you tried just writing the shutdown part separately and making it work first?

Comment: `message=="shutdown"` :_(

Comment: Looks like we have at least three reasons so far. ;-)

Comment: use .equals() to compare Strings.

Comment: @chrylis: When i use shutdown separately it is working properly it is not working inside tcp server

Comment: @Hmm: now it is exiting frm server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerSideSocket {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4020);  //Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4020");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4020");

        while (true) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
 if(message.equals("shutdown")){

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 60");
System.exit(0);

 }
 else if(message.equals("restart")){
Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc2 = runtime1.exec("shutdown -r -t 60");
System.exit(0);


 }

                System.out.println(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In code above i changed the command to execute, where you need to specify the time to shutdown and also while comparing string you need to follow like above.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter -t of shutdown needs a number (seconds to wait until shutdown/restart)

Comment: `if(message=="shutdown")` is always `false`. The statement is never reached.

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo poweroff` and read the output/errors from the process so you know what is wrong.

Also you need to use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) not `==` for comparing Strings.

BTW If all you want to do is shutdown remotely you can use SSH like this

```
ssh host-to-shitdown sudo poweroff
```

This is more secure and you don't need to write any Java code.